# Cannot disable swap

Tags: linux, fedora, swap

I have a freshly installed fedora system, and I am struggling to turn off swap.

I have checked /etc/fstab and there are no mentions of a swap partition there.
I can turn swap off with `swapoff -a` but it will be turned on again after a few seconds, with this kernel message:

```
Adding 8388604k swap on /dev/zram0.  Priority:100 extents:1 across:8388604k SSFS
```

I can see the swap device by running `swapon --show`

Does anyone have a clue where i need to disable it, if not in fstab?
All references i can find suggest that fstab is the place, and `swapoff -a` should be persistant until reboot

kernel version: 5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fedora now enables [swap on ZRAM](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SwapOnZRAM) by default. To [disable it permanently](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SwapOnZRAM#How_can_it_be_disabled.3F), remove the package which generates its configuration:

```
sudo dnf remove zram-generator-defaults
```

Comment: Thanks, worked after removing and rebooting